# hash table with linked list with bug

Tags: c, list, search, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a hashtable with linked list and there is one thing not working properly.
First i made the linked list code and made sure it worked just as it is supposed to, so I figured out it got to be something with the hashtable implementation or the interaction between them both.

What happens is i can add several objects and find them again with no problem. But if two or more objects are hashed with the same key they are supposed to create a linked list but for some reason i can only find the latest added object in the linked list.

The previously added object is there though because i can successfully delete the object that i cannot find with my "lookup_string" function, so therefor i know the object is stored at that spot.

So the function "lookup_string" is supposed to deliver the object i search for in the hash table and the "Search" function is the one i used when I only implemented the linked list. Worth mentioning is that the "Search" function is used in the delete-process but not in the process where i just want to find an object, I'm not sure if this matters because i believe the "lookup_string" should be able to find an object without the "Search" function.

So to make this simple, I store two objects:

Object 1:

```
name(key) = bcd
telephone number = 123
```

Object 2:

```
name(key) = ace
telephone number = 910
```

Now both object 1 and 2 will get the same hash-key value and therefor they will be stored in the same slot in the hash-table. They are supposed to create a linked list but when i search for the objects (choice number 3 in the menu) i can only find the latest added object, which is Object 2.
But i can still delete Object 1 and it will tell me that Object 1 was deleted successfully.

Code:

```
struct post
{   
    char name[30];          
    int tel;                
    struct post *next;      
};

typedef struct post Post;

Post *head = NULL;  
Post *current;  

struct hash_table
{
    Post **table;
    int size;
};

typedef struct hash_table Post_table;

unsigned int Hash(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    int i;
    int sum;
    int key;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tempname); i++)
    {
        sum += (int)tempname[i];
    }

    key = sum % hash_table->size;
    return key;
}

Post_table *create_hash_table(int size)
{
    int i;
    Post_table *new_table;

    if (size < 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table structure
    if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Post_table))) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table itself
    if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(Post *) * size)) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //Initialize the elements of the table
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_table->table[i] = NULL;
        new_table->size = size;
    }
    return new_table;
}

Post *lookup_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    for(list = hash_table->table[hashkey]; list != NULL; list = list->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(tempname, list->name) == 0)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], int temptel)
{
    Post *new_list;
    Post *current_list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for list */
    if ((new_list = malloc(sizeof(Post))) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /* Does item already exist? */
    current_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);
    /* item already exists, don't insert it again. */
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    /* Insert into list */

    printf("\nHash-key: %d\n", hashkey); 
    hash_table->table[hashkey] = AddList(tempname, temptel);

    return 0;
}

Post* CreateList(char tempname[30], int temptel)
{   
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);    
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%s]\n",tempname);

    head = current = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel)
{
    if (NULL == head)
    {
        return (CreateList(tempname, temptel));
    }

    printf("\n Adding node to end of list with value [%s]\n",tempname);
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    current->next = ptr;
    current = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

void skrivMeny(void)
{
    printf("\n1: Register name and telephone number\n");
    printf("2: Remove name and telephone number\n");
    printf("3: Search for name\n");
    printf("5: Exit\n");
}

Post* Search(char tempname[30], Post **prev)
{
    Post *ptr = head;
    Post *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char structname[sizeof(tempname)];

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",tempname);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {   
        if (strcmp(ptr->name, tempname) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        if(prev)
        {
            *prev = tmp;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void free_entry(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *del_list;
    Post *temp;
    int ret = 0;

    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    del_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

    ret = Delete(tempname);

    if(ret != 0)
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s]  passed \n",tempname);
    }
}

int Delete(char tempname[30])
{
    Post *prev = NULL;
    Post *del = NULL;

    printf("\n Deleting value [%s] from list\n",tempname);
    del = Search(tempname,&prev);

    if(del == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(prev != NULL)
        {
            prev->next = del->next;
        }
        if(del == current && del != head)
        {
            current = prev;
        }
        else if(del == head)
        {
            head = del->next;
        }
    }

    free(del);
    del = NULL;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    printf("\nHej och välkommen till hashlistan\n\n");
    int menyval = 1;
    char tempname[30];
    int temptel;
    int key;

    Post * ptr;

    Post_table *hash_table;
    int table_size = 10;
    hash_table = create_hash_table(table_size);

while (menyval > 0 && menyval <= 5)
{
    skrivMeny();
    scanf("%d", &menyval);

        if (menyval == 1)
        {
            printf("[Name] [Number] = ");
            scanf("%s %d", &tempname[0], &temptel);//inmatning
            add_string(hash_table, tempname, temptel);
        }

        if (menyval == 2)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            free_entry(hash_table, tempname);
        }

        if (menyval == 3)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            ptr = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

            if(ptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Search [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Search passed [name = %s tel = %d]\n",ptr->name, ptr->tel);
            }
        }
        if (menyval == 5)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate all help or tips toward solving my problem!

EDIT:
This is how my code looks like right now, I divided my file into two files; hash.c and lista.h where i included the header file in the c-file.

lista.h:

```
struct post
{   
    char name[30];          
    int tel;                
    struct post *next;      
};
typedef struct post Post;

struct list
{
    Post *head = NULL;  
    Post *current;
};
typedef struct list List;

Post* CreateList(char tempname[30], int temptel)
{   
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);    
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%s]\n",tempname);

    return ptr;
}

Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, int emptyElement)
{
    if (emptyElement == 1)
    {
        return (CreateList(tempname, temptel));
    }

    printf("\n Adding node to end of list with value [%s]\n",tempname);
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}

int Delete(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *prev = NULL;
    Post *del = NULL;

    printf("\n Deleting value [%s] from list\n",tempname);
    del = Search(tempname,&prev);

    if(del == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(prev != NULL)
        {
            prev->next = del->next;
        }
        if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].current && del != hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].current = prev;
        }
        else if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].head = del->next;
        }
    }

    free(del);
    del = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

hash.c:

```
struct hash_table
{
    List *table;
    int size;
};

typedef struct hash_table Post_table;

unsigned int Hash(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    int i;
    int sum;
    int key;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tempname); i++)
    {
        sum += (int)tempname[i];
    }

    key = sum % hash_table->size;
    return key;
}

Post_table *create_hash_table(int size)
{
    int i;
    Post_table *new_table;

    if (size < 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table structure
    if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Post_table))) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table itself
    if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(Post *) * size)) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //Initialize the elements of the table
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_table->table[i] = NULL;
        new_table->size = size;
    }
    return new_table;
}

Post *lookup_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    for(list = hash_table->table[hashkey]; list != NULL; list = list->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(tempname, list->name) == 0)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], int temptel)
{
    int emptyElement = 0;        
    Post *new_list;
    Post *current_list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for list */
    if ((new_list = malloc(sizeof(Post))) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /* Does item already exist? */
    current_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);
    /* item already exists, don't insert it again. */
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    /* Insert into list */
    if (hash_table->table[hashkey] == NULL)
    {
        emptyElement = 1;
    }

    printf("\nHash-key: %d\n", hashkey); 
    hash_table->table[hashkey] = AddList(tempname, temptel);

    if (emptyElement == 1)
    {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].head = hash_table->table[hashkey];
            hash_table->table[hashkey].current = hash_table->table[hashkey];
    }

    if (emptyElement == 0)
    {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].current = hash_table->table[hashkey];
    }

    return 0;
}

void free_entry(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *del_list;
    Post *temp;
    int ret = 0;

    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    del_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

    ret = Delete(tempname);

    if(ret != 0)
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s]  passed \n",tempname);
    }
}

void skrivMeny(void)
{
    printf("\n1: Register name and telephone number\n");
    printf("2: Remove name and telephone number\n");
    printf("3: Search for name\n");
    printf("5: Exit\n");
}

Post* Search(char tempname[30], Post **prev)
{
    Post *ptr = head;
    Post *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char structname[sizeof(tempname)];

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",tempname);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {   
        if (strcmp(ptr->name, tempname) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        if(prev)
        {
            *prev = tmp;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nHej och välkommen till hashlistan\n\n");
    int menyval = 1;
    char tempname[30];
    int temptel;
    int key;

    Post * ptr;

    Post_table *hash_table;
    int table_size = 10;
    hash_table = create_hash_table(table_size);

while (menyval > 0 && menyval <= 5)
{
    skrivMeny();
    scanf("%d", &menyval);

        if (menyval == 1)
        {
            printf("[Name] [Number] = ");
            scanf("%s %d", &tempname[0], &temptel);//inmatning
            add_string(hash_table, tempname, temptel);
        }

        if (menyval == 2)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            free_entry(hash_table, tempname);
        }

        if (menyval == 3)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            ptr = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

            if(ptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Search [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Search passed [name = %s tel = %d]\n",ptr->name, ptr->tel);
            }
        }
        if (menyval == 5)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But as I said there seems to be something wrong with this part:

```
struct list
{
    Post *head = NULL;  
    Post *current;
};
```

And since this is not correct it causes several other errors so I'm trying to see what is wrong with this part first.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your lookup function, one line at a time, with a debugger? What OS are you using? What compiler?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mentioned that this is C language and the OS is the latest Ubuntu. It's compiled with gcc, i don't remember which version. But I don't have access to my computer right now and i don't have a compiler on this computer I'm on, which is very limited so I can't install a compiler either.

Comment: My eyes, my eyes! That's a lot of code.

Comment: Yeah i noticed! I did use intends when writing my post which would have made the code much easier to read, but somehow the intends didn't apply to the final post....

Comment: actually if you use firefox the intends are showing up correctly. And also I updated my code and divided it into one c-file and one header-file where the header-file is included in the c-file. Still the same amount of code, but maybe easier to look through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here are some imporvements on your code: I've marked them with my Tag 'Leo'

In list.c:

```
struct post                 // structure of node
{   
    char name[30];          // stored data
    int tel;                // stored data
    struct post *next;      // reference to next node
};

typedef struct post Post;   // Post = struct post

struct list
{
    Post *head;         
    Post *current;              
};

typedef struct list List;

struct hash_table
{
    List *table;
    int size;
};

typedef struct hash_table Post_table;

Post* CreateList(char tempname[30], int temptel);
Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, int emptyElement, Post *current);
void skrivMeny(void);
void PrintList(void);
int Delete(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], unsigned int hashkey);
Post* Search(Post_table *hash_table, unsigned int hashkey, char tempname[30], Post **prev);

Post* CreateList(char tempname[30], int temptel)
{   
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);    
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%s]\n",tempname);

    return ptr;
}

// Leo: emptyElement isn't neccessary, we use current==null 
Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, Post *current)
{
    if( current == null )
    {
        return (CreateList(tempname, temptel));
    }

    printf("\n Adding node to end of list with value [%s]\n",tempname);
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    // Leo: we must append the new element to current
    current->next = ptr;

    return ptr;
}
```

and in hash.c

```
unsigned int Hash(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    int i;
    int sum;
    int key;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tempname); i++)
    {
        sum += (int)tempname[i];
    }

    key = sum % hash_table->size;
    return key;
}

Post_table *create_hash_table(int size)
{
    int i;
    Post_table *new_table;

    if (size < 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table structure
    if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Post_table))) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //attempt to allocate memory for the table itself
    // Leo: replaced malloc() by calloc() so all head and current are initialized with NULL
    if ((new_table->table = calloc(size, sizeof(List *) )) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //Initialize the elements of the table
    /* Leo: What's that loop for ?
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_table->table[i];        // Leo: that line doen't do anything
        new_table->size = size;     // Leo: once is enough, let's have it otside the loop
    }
    */
    new_table->size = size;       // Leo: once is enough, let's have it otside the loop
    return new_table;
}

Post *lookup_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    /* Go to the correct list based on the hash value and see if str is
    * in the list.  If it is, return return a pointer to the list element.
    * If it isn't, the item isn't in the table, so return NULL.
    */
    // Leo: we must start with head instead of current
    for(list = hash_table->table[hashkey].head; list != NULL; list = list->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(tempname, list->name) == 0)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], int temptel)
{
    //Leo: emptyElement is not used any more (see AddList()
    //int emptyElement = 0;
    //Leo: new_list is never used
    //Post *new_list;
    Post *current_list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);

    /* Attempt to allocate memory for list */
    /* Leo: new_list is never used
    if ((new_list = malloc(sizeof(Post))) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    */

    /* Does item already exist? */
    current_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);
    /* item already exists, don't insert it again. */
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    /* Insert into list */
    /* Leo: emptyElement isn't used any more 
    if (hash_table->table[hashkey].head == NULL)
    {
        emptyElement = 1;
    }
    */

    printf("\nHash-key: %d\n", hashkey);
    //This line of code under used to store my element in the hash-table but gives now an error 
    //  hash_table->table[hashkey] = AddList(tempname, temptel, emptyElement, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);

    /* Leo: in case of emptyElement == 1 you have called AddList() twice and so created two new list elemens, we replace all of this by the code below
    if (emptyElement == 1)
    {
        hash_table->table[hashkey].head = AddList(tempname, temptel, emptyElement, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);
        hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, emptyElement, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);
    }

    if (emptyElement == 0)
    {
        hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, emptyElement, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);
    }
    */

    // Leo: Note: if the list for hashKey has not been created yet then both head and current are NULL, otherwise both are != NULL
    hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);
    // Leo: if the list has been created just now, then both head and current must point to the only list element
    if( hash_table->table[hashkey].head == NULL )
         hash_table->table[hashkey].head = hash_table->table[hashkey].current;

    return 0;
}

void free_entry(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *del_list;
    Post *temp;
    int ret = 0;

    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    del_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

    ret = Delete(hash_table, tempname, hashkey);

    if(ret != 0)
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s]  passed \n",tempname);
    }
}

void skrivMeny(void)
{
    printf("\n1: Register name and telephone number\n");
    printf("2: Remove name and telephone number\n");
    printf("3: Search for name\n");
    printf("5: Exit\n");
}

Post* Search(Post_table *hash_table, unsigned int hashkey, char tempname[30], Post **prev)
{
    Post *ptr = hash_table->table[hashkey].head;
    Post *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char structname[sizeof(tempname)];

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",tempname);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {   
        if (strcmp(ptr->name, tempname) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        if(prev)
        {
            *prev = tmp;
        }
    return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}


int main()
{
    printf("\nHej och välkommen till hashlistan\n\n");
    int menyval = 1;
    char tempname[30];
    int temptel;
    int key;

    Post * ptr;

    Post_table *hash_table;
    int table_size = 10;
    hash_table = create_hash_table(table_size);

    while (menyval > 0 && menyval <= 5)
    {
        skrivMeny();
        scanf("%d", &menyval);

        if (menyval == 1)
        {
            printf("[Name] [Number] = ");
            scanf("%s %d", &tempname[0], &temptel);//inmatning
            add_string(hash_table, tempname, temptel);
        }

        if (menyval == 2)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            free_entry(hash_table, tempname);
        }

        if (menyval == 3)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            ptr = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

            if(ptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Search [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Search passed [name = %s tel = %d]\n",ptr->name, ptr->tel);
            }
        }

        if (menyval == 5)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


int Delete(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], unsigned int hashkey)
{
    Post *prev = NULL;
    Post *del = NULL;

    printf("\n Deleting value [%s] from list\n",tempname);
    del = Search(hash_table, hashkey, tempname, &prev);

    if(del == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        if(prev != NULL)
        {
            prev->next = del->next;
        }

        if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].current && del != hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].current = prev;
        }

        else if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].head = del->next;
        }
    }

    free(del);
    del = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

I have not compiled it, so now there may be some syntax errors, but I hope its clear how the whole thing should work. If you have some more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: The only syntax-error which appeared that I was unsure of was: `hash.c:42:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘calloc’` which points to this line `if ((new_table->table = calloc(sizeof(List *) * size)) == NULL)` And I replaced it with `if ((new_table->table = calloc(0,sizeof(List *) * size)) == NULL)` But now I get a segmentation fault whenever I try to search the list and it crashes. 2 times out of 10 i didn't get a segmentation fault but then I still couldn't find the element with the search function.

Comment: Ouch,  `calloc()` should be `calloc( size, sizeof(List *) )`. The parameters are 'number of elements' and 'size of element' (look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc)). The way you called it, it allocated `0 * ( sizeof(List *) * size )` thus nothing at all. I've corrected the error in the answer.

Comment: Okay i see! Now I got it running properly and I can store things in the table and it seems like it's creating lists since it says adding node to end of list. But it still fails to find the stored elements, I will look through the searching-logics and see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Hi again! Just wanted to tell you that I finally got the code to work as it should. It can now store, find and delete elements from the hash table. Thank you so much for your patience and effort Ingo Leonhardt, this was a huge break through for me and I wouldn't have made it without your help! So thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry if I got it wrong but as far as I can tell your lookup_string() function traverses to the last element of the hash table(the one most recently added).
Try traversing it the other way round or use a doubly linked list.

P.S: Y dont you use your search function with a lil bit of customization? Y this redundancy of lookup and search?

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi! Do you mean that my lookup_string() only looks at the last element and skips all the elements before that? 

Yes it is a bit redundancy because of the way I approached it by implementing the Linked-list first and then the hash-table but the redundancy will be fixed when i got the logic to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem results in mixing **one** linked list and the hash table. The list is not sorted, so the hash table cannot point to a list position where all elements with a given key can be found. And furthermore `AddList()` returns the new list element which is appended to the end and that is stored in `hash_table->table[hashkey]`.
That's why you only find tha last element (as Mudassir Razvi has already pointed out). 
So you should either create one list per hash key (the simplest solution I suppose) or sort your list per hash key and assign `hash_table->table[hashkey]` only when you add the first element with that key (==> `if( hash_table->table[hashkey] == NULL )`)

EDIT:
If you want to create separate lists for each key, of course you can't have global variables `head` and `current` anymore but one pair per key. So you can define:

```
struct list {
    Post *head;
    Post *current;
}
```

and let `hash_table->table` be an attray of `struct list` instead of `Post`. `CreateList()` already returns `head` so you can directly assign it to `table[key].head` and `table[key].current`. Now everything else you have to do is pass the actual `current` to `AddList()` and then set `table[key].current` to `AddList()`'s return value.
That's a kind of road map, I think you will come along.

Comment: Okay i think i understood most of what you said. I should only assign 'hash_table->table[hashkey]' when  i add the first element, all the other elements with the same hash key should just be pointed at through the previous elements' "next-pointer"?

Altough i don't understand why I need to have the list sorted. If I don't have many elements in each list i can just let the search go through the unsorted list until it finds the correct element. I just need to tell which list it should look in, which i believe is done by 'list = hash_table->table[hashkey];'

Comment: Well at the moment there is only **one common** list for all hash keys defined by the global variables `head` and `current` where every new element is appended to, and that list isn't sorted. So your hash table might tell you where you find  the first element with a given key, but from that point on you might have to search to the end of the list to find a given name. If you had one list per key or a sorted list you had to examine at most as many elements as you have to that key.

Comment: Oh now I see the problem.     'head' is global and that's why creating a linked list will only occur for the first element. I guess i should put     'head' and     'current' in the CreateList() function and check as you said (     'if(hash_table->table[hashkey] == NULL) ') to know when to trigger the CreateList() function.
The problem when     'head' and     current' becomes local is that I think the pointers lose their target value. Every list will have their own "head" and "current" but they will get lost as the CreateList() function ends.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and put the `Post *head` and `Post *current` in a struct and then I intepreted your sentence "and let `hash_table->table` be an attray of `struct list` instead of `Post`" as  changing the `Post **table;` to `struct list **table` in the struct hash_table. But the compiler complained about an error at the `Post *head;` with the message: `error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token`. Im sorry if I misinterpeted your tips but im really out of my comfort-zone of programming right now.

Comment: In your comment you wrote a ';' in `Post **table;` but not in `struct list **table`. In the real source too? That would explain the compiler error. Btw. yout only need `struct list *table;` as you want to have a `struct list` per key, not a `struct list *`. If that doesn't help, please post the cutrrent code.

Comment: I'm sorry this was just a mistake i made in the comment, in the real source code the format is correct with ";" and all. That error still occurs and it points to the exact location right after `Post` in `Post *head = NULL;`. I will update my post with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

*I decided to post a new answer regarding the current code, because I find otherwise it would be even more unreadable to another person than it is now*

The syntax error in your current code is here:

```
struct list 
{
    Post *head = NULL;  
    Post *current;
};
```

This is not a variable definition but only a declaration of a struct. Thus you cannot do any assignments (`= NULL`) here because there is simply no variable to assign it to. 
Instead you could either initialize `hash_table->table[i].head` in a loop after allocating the array or just call `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` which initializes the allocated buffer with `'\0'`.

I guess there are more errors in your code, at least I found

```
if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(Post *) * size)) == NULL)
```

that should be

```
if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(list stuct) * size)) == NULL) // or calloc()
```

But I can't review everything by now.
Hope that gives you enough to continue,

Comment: Thank you so much! I succeded to continue by quite alot and solved several of other bugs. Now I only have bugs caused by what seems like the same kind of error. It seems like all of the problems now have to do with using `hash_table->table[hashkey]` which is of type `List` in operations of assigning values with another type. For instance in "lookup_string i have a for-loop which assigns it's value to `list` which is of type `struct Post*` and in the "add_string" I assign the return value from `AddList` which is of type `struct Post*` to `hash_table->table[hashkey].head` which is of type `List`

Comment: Also it seems lika i can't compare it or assign it with `NULL` either.

Comment: not` table[i]` itself, because it's not a pointer array, but `table[i].head` and `table[i].current` can be assigned with and compared to `NULL`

Comment: Okay but how do i store the return value from AddList into the hashtable slot? `hash_table->table[hashkey] = AddList(tempname, temptel);` was suppose to return the element into the hash table but it gives error because AddList returns a `struct Post*` and the table is a `struct list`

Comment: just `hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, hash_table->table[hashkey].current );` You pass the previous list current (which may be NULL) and receive the new `current` (which you must also copy to `hash_table->table[hashkey].head` if `head` has been `NULL`. Note that either both `head` and `current` should be `NULL` or none.

Comment: Okay so i get the error: `expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘->’ token` at `Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, List hash_table->table[hashkey].current)` in the function name. And a warning saying: `Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, int emptyElement, List hash_table->table[hashkey].current)` at `hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, emptyElement, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);` where I did as you said.

Comment: `hash_table->table[hashkey].current` is correct when you *call* the function, in the declaration the parameter must be just `Post *current` (which replaces the global variable you had before). But it's difficult to tell without the code, so just post the code again if you need some more help.

Comment: Okay I seem to have solved all the compilation. As I run the code I can't find an element I've stored and so I am not sure if I even succeed to store it correctly. There is one line I had to remove that I suspect can be the cause of this problem. Before I introduced the head and current pointers as a struct. I used to store the actual element with `hash_table->table[hashkey] = AddList(tempname, temptel);` But since now i can't assign anything to `hash_table->table[hashkey]` I just removed that line and I think I never store the actual element with the name and number in the hash table.

Comment: All I store are the head and current pointers. How are you supposed to store the actual element into the hast table? I will post the code tomorrow when I have time to format the whole code so it has correct format according to Stackoverflow, which means replacing every intent with four spaces.... Or maybe I could upload or send the files to you?

Comment: post the code in SO please, so you have the chance that someone else might help you too. I will really try but I don't have too much time at the moment.

Comment: okay I made a new post and put up exactly how my current code looks like now.